# How can I convert a simple java swing code into javafx code using netbeans 7.3.1 IDE

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

Is there any way by which I can convert a simple java swing application which I have already developed in simple java swing using JFrameForm into javaFX? is there
any library or something?